# What does "electrical typical" mean?

Tags: translation, technical

I stumbled upon the following text:

> Motor starting circuits In the table above is mentioned which
>   electrical typical has to be used for the motor starting circuits. The
>   attached electrical typicals (see ...) have to be respected by the
>   contractor.

Could you explain what does "electrical typicals" mean? It looks like a noun but google and wiktionary only give explanations for adjective.

Comment: I believe it is written by somebody who is not a native English speaker. My guess is that _typical_ is a bad translation from another language, and should be translated as _standard_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I do not believe the cited text is valid English from a native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There was a chance that it's some kind of technical jargon, because I've seen this phrase before in some job applications from US and Canada.

Comment: @Andrei: Nah - there was never any chance of that, given how many other elements within OP's cited text are quite obviously ungrammatical forms typical of a non-native speaker.

Comment: This question would be better asked at electronics.stackexchange.com.